# Toggle Database Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method defined as athlete which is founder in the user model and and a boolean column defined as athlete with the default value of false.

The provider is either twitter or facebook, if the provider is not any of those and blank then I want it to just toggle the athlete column to true in the method below.

```
 def athlete?
    provider.blank?
  end
```

I tried multiple things but have no luck like toggle method below no luck.

```
 def athlete?
    provider.blank?
    user.toggle!(:athlete)
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know the column type of the Provider, I'm assuming it's a string with possible values of "facebook", "twitter", and "". Try something like this and let me know what you get

```
def athlete?
  !provider.any? { |p| %w(facebook twitter).include?(p) }
end
```

All this does is checks if the provider contains "twitter" or "facebook", if not, then return true.

If you would like to update the attribute, then do something like this:

```
def athlete=(athlete)
  self[:athlete] = !provider.nil? && !provider.any? { |p| %w(facebook twitter).include?(p) } rescue true
end
```

Comment: Correct its either twitter, facebook or blank. I'd like to update the attribute so I tried the second method and got this error: `code`undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you creating a new record? If so, then the "provider" isn't being set and that's what's causing the error. I'll update my block of code to default to "true" in the case of an error. Let me know how you're using the code, are you Creating a new record? Updating? Viewing?

Comment: i'm creating a new record but by default the provider should be blank and the athlete column should be false then set to true if the provider is blank. Its working now error free but its not saving the changes to the database so the athlete column is still false. Thanks

Comment: Try the save method now (I've edited my response above). Notice the `athlete=(athlete)` change. This will cause the athlete record to be filtered before being saved. I also added a `nil?` check for the provider. Now, if the provider is not given, then athlete will be FALSE. If the provider is given, and doesn't contain facebook or twitter, athlete is FALSE. However, if provider is given and contains facebook or twitter, athlete is TRUE. Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks. Its suppose to be in the reverse if there is no provider then make it true but if its twitter and facebook make it false. I'll attempt to reverse it and try it out. Thanks!